# How to add a new row to the registration form?

Tags: users

I'm using [LoginToboggan](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) module. Via this module user can register or login.

And now I want to add another row to this form. For example: *Phone number* or *Age*.

How can I achieve this? Or is there another way of achieving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without using LoginToboggan also you can achieve you requirement.

1. Goto **Configuration** > **Account settings** > **Manage Field** and then add field.
2. In field configuration **Display on user registration form** checkbox.

[image]